Multiple navigation menus for different screens
I want to understand if it is possible to create several navigation tabs in the react-navigation package. Since I need to show the user a huge number of tabs and they simply do not fit on the screen. For example, on the home screen there are Homepage and Dashboard tabs, but on the Dashboard screen there are Settings and Profile tabs. I searched the documentation for information for about an hour, but did not find what I needed.
